# Box shadow animation is bugging on Safari browsers

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I have simple box-shadow animation on my website (build in Elementor, WordPress). The animation works perfectly fine on Chrome but on Safari, it creates this weird square animation (for both mobile and laptops):

[image]

This is the CSS I used to create the Box Shadow animation. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```css
.hero_button_homepage svg{
     border-radius: 150px!important;
    animation: pulse-orange 2s infinite!important;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-color: red;
}
@keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_button_homepage">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
       <div class="elementor-icon-box-icon">
          <a class="" href="">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="86" height="86" viewBox="0 0 86 86" fill="none"><path d="M57.5 43.866L38 55.1244C37.3333 55.5093 36.5 55.0281 36.5 54.2583L36.5 31.7417C36.5 30.9719 37.3333 30.4907 38 30.8756L57.5 42.134C58.1667 42.5189 58.1667 43.4811 57.5 43.866Z" stroke="#F9F6F1" stroke-width="2"></path><circle cx="43" cy="43" r="42" stroke="#F9AC66" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"></circle></svg>               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="elementor-icon-box-content">
                <h3 class="elementor-icon-box-title">
                    <a href=""> Watch the full video</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your svg in a wrapper and apply your animation to that. Animations on SVG can be tricky, because your path can cut of certain stuff, to achieve it's look.

Furthermore your HTML is poorly indented which may be why you have a closing `div` tag under you `svg` which does not have any corresponding opening tag. Your closing `a` tag is "hidden" all the way at the end of your svg line.

Clean that up and wrap your svg and you should be good to go.

**NOTE:** I applied `margin: 5rem;` to you `.hero_button_homepage` to make it clear that it works. Remember to remove that before you implement the below.

**Edit:**
Im pretty sure you should prefix animations with `-webkit-` and `-moz-` **BEFORE** your *normal* declartion: E.g:

```
.foo-bar {
    -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
}
```

You can see which prefixes you should use on [shouldiprefix.com](https://shouldiprefix.com)

```css
.hero_button_homepage { margin: 5rem; }
.hero_button_homepage .svg_wrapper {
     border-radius: 150px!important;
    animation: pulse-orange 2s infinite!important;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-color: red;
}
.hero_button_homepage svg {
     border-radius: 150px!important;
    animation: pulse-orange 2s infinite!important;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-color: red;
}

@keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse-orange {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 0 rgba(249,172,102,0.7);
    }
    
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 20px rgba(249, 172, 102, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_button_homepage">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-icon-box-wrapper">
       <div class="elementor-icon-box-icon">
          <a class="" href="">
             <div class="svg_wrapper">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="86" height="86" viewBox="0 0 86 86" fill="none"><path d="M57.5 43.866L38 55.1244C37.3333 55.5093 36.5 55.0281 36.5 54.2583L36.5 31.7417C36.5 30.9719 37.3333 30.4907 38 30.8756L57.5 42.134C58.1667 42.5189 58.1667 43.4811 57.5 43.866Z" stroke="#F9F6F1" stroke-width="2"></path><circle cx="43" cy="43" r="42" stroke="#F9AC66" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"></circle></svg>               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="elementor-icon-box-content">
                <h3 class="elementor-icon-box-title">
                    <a href=""> Watch the full video</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```